# In what reaction of mitochondrial respiration is hydrogen peroxide an anomalous product?

Tags: biochemistry, cellular-respiration, mitochondria

I understand that hydrogen peroxide is produced in an anomalous manner during mitochondrial respiration, which also produces other by-products or free radicals. Does anyone know the details of the specific reaction in which hydrogen peroxide is formed and what is the normal product(s) of the reaction?

Comment: The normal product of mitochondrial respiration is water. Perhaps "incomplete reduction" would be a better phrase than "unpaired reduction".

Comment: Perhaps rare, but I think that's exactly what cytochrome c oxidase does.

Comment: I found your question unclear, which is why I have voted to close it. I do not think merely asking about the product is sufficient to justify it so I have changed it to ask for the details of the reaction (which will include the product).

Comment: I'm sorry but I have modified the question to make it more comprehensive. If you can expand your answer, with links to supporting references, please do so.